# Files on github & hostng

Tags: git, heroku, github, deployment, hosting

Files for server and files for saving in commits are not the same thing.
For example:

**1) Logins and Passwords for DB.**

When app is deployed on a server, it has to have access to db. But it's unacceptable to keep password on public commits.

**2) Products of compiling.**

I use typescript, which all the time compile .ts to .js. Javascript files doesn't have any value. That's why you should not keep them on git. But when you need to deploy your app on the server you have to make the commit with the garbage files.

**Therefore**, the question arises: how can I don't store garbage files in commits, but be able to do deploy on the server?

Comment: I don't know about heroku, but most targets that deploy from public git repo have secure (encrypted) variables (not available from pull requests for security). For example, [Travis](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/) and [AppVeyor](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-configuration/#secure-variables).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

**1. You could create branch**

```
git checkout -b my-branch
```

**2. Make compilation, decrypt password etc. Then make commit in the branch.**

```
git add .
git commit -m "deploy"
```

**3. Now time to deploy that branch on server:**

```
git push heroku -f my-branch:master
```

That's it!

**-f** means the push is not ancestor of last push. It's necesary, bacouse you create new branches all the time. So inheritance isn't saved.

**my-branch:master** that you say heroku show my-branch like master.

After that you could just delete the branch and continue development.

```
git checkout master
git branch -D my-branch
```